# How to Display Smart banner of an application in I-phone app search bar?

Tags: ios, reactjs, iphone, react-native

I want to display my app in iphone app search bar with install button.
Something like this
[image]

Right now I can see my app with view button when I press view it will redirect to app store.

1. When we install app once and uninstall it then it will show install button like attached image of myntra app ?
2. For that do I need to add some meta tag inside my react native application for achieve this ?

Kindly share your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: There is nothing you need to or can do to influence what spotlight search shows in this instance

Comment: Thanks, I found out it's default behaviour of spotlight search. By default application banner will show according to Installation history of app in device.